# Auto update not happening if internet is through proxy for webapp as a service

Tags: install4j

Auto update is not happening if the system is connected to internet through proxy. I can access `http://gt-test-asca-release.xxx/GreytipAstra_windows_3_0_1.exe` through chrome browser (I have configured proxy in chrome browser) but my app built using install4j is unable to auto update. I see in task manager that bgupdater.exe is running. kindly help.

Note: Auto update happens successfully if computer is connected directly to internet without proxy.

**Edit 1:** Below is the jstack log:

```
2017-10-17 02:28:57
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode, sharing):

"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x04ecb400 nid=0x2758 waiting on condition [0x0507e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x29bf92d0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-Shutdown" prio=6 tid=0x05118400 nid=0x3cf4 in Object.wait() [0x04f5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x29bf9418> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x29bf9418> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x04e80000 nid=0x385c runnable [0x04fef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x04e7f000 nid=0x1eec in Object.wait() [0x04caf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x29bf94a8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x29bf94a8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x01ffa400 nid=0x1df4 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01ff7c00 nid=0x2b00 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01ff6400 nid=0x30c0 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01ff4c00 nid=0xdfc runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x01f81c00 nid=0x18a8 in Object.wait() [0x0439f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x29a7ce48> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x29a7ce48> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01f80400 nid=0x238c in Object.wait() [0x0430f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x29a7ced8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x29a7ced8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"main" prio=6 tid=0x01f5c800 nid=0x43ec in Object.wait() [0x0124e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x29c13b80> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x29c13b80> (a java.awt.Component$AWTTreeLock)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.util.CustomDialog.setVisible(CustomDialog.java:26)
    at com.install4j.runtime.util.StandardDialog.setVisible(StandardDialog.java:44)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyDialog.setVisible(ProxyDialog.java:70)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyConfig$15.run(ProxyConfig.java:283)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyConfig.showInternal(ProxyConfig.java:289)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyConfig.access$1300(ProxyConfig.java:25)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyConfig$20.run(ProxyConfig.java:401)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.RunAction.execute(RunAction.java:11)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionDirect(HelperCommunication.java:271)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionInt(HelperCommunication.java:246)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionChecked(HelperCommunication.java:184)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ProxyConfig.show(ProxyConfig.java:398)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.handleProxyFailure(HttpRequestHandler.java:322)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.getURLConnection(HttpRequestHandler.java:277)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.connect(HttpRequestHandler.java:124)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:151)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:24)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.connect(HttpRequestHandler.java:117)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:146)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.update.CheckForUpdateAction.execute(CheckForUpdateAction.java:35)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.SystemInstallOrUninstallAction.install(SystemInstallOrUninstallAction.java:29)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$9.executeAction(ContextImpl.java:1701)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$9.fetchValue(ContextImpl.java:1692)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$9.fetchValue(ContextImpl.java:1689)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.FetchObjectAction.execute(FetchObjectAction.java:14)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionDirect(HelperCommunication.java:271)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionInt(HelperCommunication.java:246)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionChecked(HelperCommunication.java:184)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.fetchObjectChecked(HelperCommunication.java:167)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.performActionIntStatic(ContextImpl.java:1689)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.performActionInt(InstallerContextImpl.java:159)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.performAction(ContextImpl.java:1114)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeAction(Controller.java:377)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeActions(Controller.java:343)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleCommand(Controller.java:204)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleStartup(Controller.java:125)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:82)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Application.runApplication(Application.java:91)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Application.main(Application.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:81)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x01f7ec00 nid=0x25cc runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x01fff000 nid=0x3f00 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 409
```

**Edit 2:**
Below is the log when I don't pass any proxy details as arguments to background update downloader but the proxy is configured in windows 10 as well as in my default browser (Google chrome):

```
[INFO] logger started at Tue Oct 24 02:00:00 IST 2017
[INFO] executable name: C:\Program Files (x86)\Greytip Astra\.install4j\bgupdater.exe
[INFO] install4j version: 7.0.3 (build 7072)
[INFO] Properties: 
-- listing properties --
install4j.shutdownFile=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\i4jshd687484241557081...
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
exe4j.moduleName=C:\Program Files (x86)\Greytip Astra\...
sun.boot.library.path=c:\program files (x86)\greytip astra\...
exe4j.semaphoreName=Local\c:_program_files_(x86)_greytip_...
java.vm.version=24.80-b11
install4j.fromService=false
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator=;
exe4j.consoleCodepage=cp0
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.script=
user.country=US
sun.os.patch.level=
install4j.exeDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Greytip Astra\...
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Greytip Astra
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_80-b15
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=c:\program files (x86)\greytip astra\...
os.arch=x86
java.io.tmpdir=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\
line.separator=

java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.variant=
exe4j.tempDir=
os.name=Windows NT (unknown)
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
java.library.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Greytip Astra\...
install4j.launcherId=626
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=51.0
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler
exe4j.isInstall4j=true
os.version=10.0
install4j.swt=false
user.home=C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
user.timezone=Asia/Calcutta
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.specification.version=1.7
file.encoding=Cp1252
user.name=ABHISHEK-PC$
java.class.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Greytip Astra\...
java.vm.specification.version=1.7
sun.arch.data.model=32
java.home=c:\program files (x86)\greytip astra\jre
sun.java.command=C:\Program Files (x86)\Greytip Astra\...
exe4j.launchName=C:\PROGRA~2\GREYTI~1\INSTAL~1\BGUPDA~...
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.language=en
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing
exe4j.unextractedPosition=0
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.ext.dirs=c:\program files (x86)\greytip astra\...
sun.boot.class.path=c:\program files (x86)\greytip astra\...
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
install4j.appDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Greytip Astra\
file.separator=\
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
apple.awt.UIElement=true
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
install4j.alternativeLogfile=E:/install4j-log/bgupdater.txt
install4j.keepLog=true
sun.desktop=windows
sun.cpu.isalist=pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+m...
[INFO] Variable changed: sys.resolveUserSpecificInstallationDir=false[class java.lang.String]
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction [ID 628]: Execute action
       Property rollbackScript: null
       Property script: com.install4j.script.I4jScript_Internal_237
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Execute action successful after 9 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.update.CheckForUpdateAction [ID 629]: Execute action
       Property connectTimeout: 10000
       Property connectionFailureScript: null
       Property readTimeout: 20000
       Property requestHeaders: []
       Property url: http://gt-test-asca-release.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/updates.xml
       Property variable: updateDescriptor
       Property acceptAllCertificates: false
       Property askForProxy: true
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Property showError: true
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.update.CheckForUpdateAction [ID 629]: could not download file
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.getURLConnection(HttpRequestHandler.java:258)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.connect(HttpRequestHandler.java:124)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:151)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:24)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.connect(HttpRequestHandler.java:117)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:146)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.update.CheckForUpdateAction.execute(CheckForUpdateAction.java:35)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.SystemInstallOrUninstallAction.install(SystemInstallOrUninstallAction.java:29)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$9.executeAction(ContextImpl.java:1701)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$9.fetchValue(ContextImpl.java:1692)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl$9.fetchValue(ContextImpl.java:1689)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.FetchObjectAction.execute(FetchObjectAction.java:14)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionDirect(HelperCommunication.java:271)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionInt(HelperCommunication.java:246)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionChecked(HelperCommunication.java:184)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.fetchObjectChecked(HelperCommunication.java:167)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.performActionIntStatic(ContextImpl.java:1689)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.performActionInt(InstallerContextImpl.java:159)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.performAction(ContextImpl.java:1114)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeAction(Controller.java:377)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeActions(Controller.java:343)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleCommand(Controller.java:204)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleStartup(Controller.java:125)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:82)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Application.runApplication(Application.java:91)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Application.main(Application.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:81)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
        Execute action not successful after 10173 ms
[INFO] Canceled
```

**Edit 3:**
I added `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` in below code yet getting same log as **EDIT 2**. Below is the code snippet:

```
ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication("626", new String[]{"-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true","-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=E:/install4j-log/bgupdater.txt","-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true"}, false, new ApplicationLauncher.Callback() {
```

Regarding system proxy and proxy credentials I have added the snapshot of it below:

**system proxy:**

[image]

**Proxy credentials:**

[image]

Comment: Add `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true` as a VM parameter to your background updater, then you can check its log file in the %TEMP% directory.

Comment: I am not getting any logs. And one more thing wanted to get clarified that how install4j knows about the proxy server?I have not provided the proxy details while installing my app. Kindly help.

Comment: Also I have added jstack log as **EDIT 1** in question. Kindly help.

Comment: The stacktrace shows that the proxy dialog is currently being displayed. install4j uses the system proxy if configured.

Comment: No proxy dialog is shown and system proxy is also configured. Kindly help.

Comment: The stack trace shows that the process is showing the dialog. Could it be behind some other window? Does the process have access to the windowing system?

Comment: I tried in muliple systems same issue exists. No dialog box is shown. And how to check that the process have access to the windowing system?

Comment: Is the updater maybe started from a service? Did you pass the "-q" flag to it?

Comment: Yes my app is a webapp running as service. And yes I am passing "-q" in code `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate(Arrays.asList("-q"), false, null);` . Kindly help.

Comment: `UpdateChecker.executeScheduledUpdate` is not relevant here, it is the background updater that is hanging. The background updater must be started in unattended mode. On the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step, select the background updater and set the "Default execution mode" property to "Unattended"

Comment: Now if I see the task manager, The bgupdater.exe gets executed and ends the process but still my app is not getting updated. I have configured proxy in windows. And is there a provision that the user can configure proxy while installing the app or can we provide proxy details programatically?

Comment: In GUI mode, the user can select a proxy and you can alos provide it programmatically, see https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/installers/downloads.html   Also, now you should add `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true` to the updater and check the log file in the %TEMP% directory to see why the update downloader has not downloaded a new installer.

Comment: VM parameters for Background update downloader is `-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true -Dinstall4j.keepLog=true` but I am not gettings any log files. Kindly help.

Comment: On macOS, look in $TMPDIR, the file name starts with "i4_log"

Comment: I am on windows 10. Kindly help. I am not getting any logs in %TEMP% directory

Comment: I have also noticed that there are some logs that gets generated while manually installing my app in %TEMP% directory. But those are not relevant. We are interested in the logs of update downloader as said by you. So kindly help.

Comment: I passed proxy details and proxy credentials to VM parameters for Background update downloader and Auto update worked. But still no logs are left by  Background update downloader. Kindly help.

Comment: Try `-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=<path to writable log file>` to write the log file to a particular file. These arguments have to be passed to the background updater.

Comment: I have added the logs as **EDIT 2** in question for logs when I don't pass any proxy details as arguments to background update downloader but the proxy is configured in windows 10 as well as in my default browser (Google chrome)

Comment: The browser proxy will not be used. What kind of system proxy did you configure? Does it change if `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` is passed to the updater?

Comment: Added comments in **EDIT 3** section of the question. Kindly help.

Comment: I would guess that the problem is that the credentials are not applied. For a background updater a proxy with credentials does not work unless you set them explicitly with -DproxyAuthUser=... and -DproxyAuthPassword=...